# How to map Web-Services key and values pairs using NSObject?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsobject

Hi I have used NsurlSession for integrating web services when I get response from services I am using NSObject for mapping key and values pairs.

After the process is done in NSObject class I want to display that data in my TableList.

For this I wrote the code below, but after mapping all objects in my NSObject class.

How can I display them in tableList?

Please help me.

### mainclass:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

    BacGroundGetMethodServiceClass * get;
    ModelObject1 * model1;
    NSString * alertmessage;
    UITableView * MaintableView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    get = [[BacGroundGetMethodServiceClass alloc]init];
    get.delegate = self;
    [get getServieCalling:@"my url"];

    model1 = [[ModelObject1 alloc]init];
}

//got response here from services using protocols

- (void) GetCallService1: (id)MainResponse{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if ([MainResponse isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && MainResponse[@"error"]){

            alertmessage = [MainResponse objectForKey:@"message"];
            [self ShowingAlertMesaage:alertmessage];

        }else if ([MainResponse count] == 0){

            [self ShowingAlertMesaage:@"Server not responding please try again"];
        }
        else{

            [model1 loadingservices :MainResponse];
         }
    });
}

//Crating TableList :-

-(void)createTableList{

    //Create UITableList:-
    [MaintableView removeFromSuperview];
    MaintableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 118, self.view.frame.size.width-10, self.view.frame.size.height-75)  style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    MaintableView.delegate = self;
    MaintableView.dataSource = self;
    MaintableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    MaintableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    MaintableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 75, 0);
    MaintableView.bounces = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:MaintableView];
}

//TableList Delegate Methods:-

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";

    // Similar to UITableViewCell, but
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}
@end
```

### model Object class:-

```
#import "ModelObject1.h"

@implementation ModelObject1

@synthesize MasterId,Name;

-(void)loadingservices :(id)mainDictionary{

    for (NSDictionary *obj in mainDictionary) {

        if([obj objectForKey:@"Name"] && [obj objectForKey:@"id"]) {

            Name = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"];
            MasterId = [obj objectForKey:@"id"];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list then you need array in proper JSON object.
i.e

```
(
    {
        Name = value1,
        MasterId = value2
    },
    {
        Name = value1,
        MasterId = value2
    },
    {
        Name = value1,
        MasterId = value2
    }
)
```

You need to create multiple objects of `ModelObject1`, i.e if in your JSON array you have 3 objects then you need to create 3 object of your `ModelObject1`.

You can achieve this by creating new Method or Class.

for example here is some code.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
    {
        ModelObject1 *model1 = [[ModelObject1 alloc]init];
        [model1 loadingservices :array[i];
        //store model1 in to any array and use that array to display list in array.
    }
```

You can display the data as below.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return yourModelClassArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";

    // Similar to UITableViewCell, but
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    ModelObject1 *model1 = yourModelClassArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = model1.Name;
    return cell;
```

}

Comment: by the how to get json data in array.count

Comment: You will get that in `MainResponse `.

Comment: NSArray *array = [MainResponse valueForKey:@"Name"];

Comment: No its not enough, you need to check your JSON data, in JSON data you will get some array.
i.e `{arrayKeyName=({keyName=value},{keyName=value},{keyName=value})}`

Comment: Can you post your json data? i.e `MainResponse`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108147/discussion-between-krish-and-jatin-chauhan).